# How to solve the following equation?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, logarithms

I have been given this equation for homework and I don't know how to solve it.

$y=\dfrac{\ln\left(\dfrac{x}{m}-sa\right)}{r^2}$

Comment: http://www.reddit.com/r/math/comments/1tbh9o/math_masters_of_reddit_is_this_correct_merry/ and its link http://imgur.com/uMHc7I3

Comment: mathematical "merry x-mas" $\ddot \smile$

Answer (score 5, accepted):

$y=\dfrac{\ln\left(\dfrac{x}{m}-sa\right)}{r^2}$
$y=\dfrac{\ln\left(\dfrac{x}{m}-as\right)}{r^2}$ , then we have
$r^2y=\ln\left(\dfrac{x}{m}-as\right)$
$e^{r^2y}=\dfrac{x}{m}-as$
$me^{r^2y}=x-mas$
$me^{rry}=x-mas$